# Confusing list of existing retina face libraries

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, face, facial-identification

There are quite a number of currently existing retina faces libraries with exactly same pip implementation.

1. Take for instance:
   `pip install retinaface` (https://pypi.org/project/retinaface/#description), with an import:
   `from retinaface import RetinaFace`
2. Another again is:
   `pip install retina-face` (https://pypi.org/project/retina-face/#description), with an import:
   `from retinaface import RetinaFace`
3. Another again is:
   `pip install retinaface_pytorch` (https://pypi.org/project/retinaface-pytorch/)
   `from retinaface.pre_trained_models import get_model`

Has anyone worked with these and how do you code if you intend to use different aspects of each library?